# unrecognized option '-mfloat-abi=softfp' in config.log file

Tags: cross-compiling

when i was cross compiling mutt-1.5.20 for arm then during configure i am getting error
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details.
In config.log file below message
configure:2925: checking for C compiler default output file name
configure:2947: /home/hems-pc2/Downloads/linux-devkit/bin/arm-arago-linux-gnueabi-gcc    conftest.c  >&5
**as: unrecognized option '-mfloat-abi=softfp'**
configure:2951: $? = 1
configure:2989: result:

The command used for configure:
build_arm$../configure --host=arm-arago-linux-gnueabi  CC=/home/hems-pc2/Downloads/linux-devkit/bin/arm-arago-linux-gnueabi-gcc CXX=/home/hems-pc2/Downloads/linux-devkit/bin/arm-arago-linux-gnueabi-g++ --enable-so --with-named-curses-libs=-lncurses --without-man --without-docs ac_cv_sys_restartable_syscalls=no ac_cv_conv_longlong_to_float=yes --with-zlib

Let me know what i am missing.
Thanks for advance

Priyea